# Start applescript when itunes starts

Tags: scripting, applescript, itunes

Any way to bind an applescript to iTunes so that when iTunes is started the applescript is run?

I have a script that runs continuously monitoring iTunes but it seems a waste to have it running even if iTunes is not running.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do when I tunes is open ?

Comment: It monitors your listening and sends the data to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a simple AppleScript or automator program that when you open it it runs the apple script you want and iTunes at the same time. Also you could name the Automator program iTunes and put the iTunes icon as the icon.Here's an example if you don't know how to change to icon just ask. http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=2032126&id=1254776036&l=b240595cc1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually decided to go with a Cocoa daemon along with distributed notifications.